# How to add a view programmatically to RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Can you give me a very simple example of adding child view programmatically  to `RelativeLayout` at a given position?

For example, to reflect the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="107dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="103dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

I don't understand how to create an appropriate `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` instance.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Heres an example to get you started, fill in the rest as applicable:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
params.leftMargin = 107
...
mRelativeLayout.addView(tv, params);
```

The docs for RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and the constructors are [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#RelativeLayout.LayoutParams%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: Sorry, the same question: where did you learn about `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` constructor without a `Context` as first parameter?

Comment: Ah, sorry was thinking width and height should be exact values.

Comment: I was looking for this! Even though it seems my view does not apply the params...

Answer (score 30):

Firstly, you should give an id to your RelativeLayout let say relativeLayout1.

```
RelativeLayout mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
TextView mTextView = new TextView(context);
mTextView.setText("Dynamic TextView");
mTextView.setId(111);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
mainLayout.addView(mTextView, params);
```

Comment: Where is `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` constructor described? It is not here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html since all prototypes have `Context` as first parameter.

Comment: You should check here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

It is RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(int w, int h)

Comment: What is `R.id.relativeLayout1` referring to?

Comment: @SiKni8 It is the id of the TextView parent Layout, a Relative layout that is already on the xml file.