# How do I specify layout_below programmatically for a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to do something like this programmatically -

```
<RelativeLayout1>
  <LinearLayout name = 1>
  <LinearLayout below = 1>
<RelativeLayout1>
```

I try to do this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)mButtonContainer.getLayoutParams();
```

params have `weight` field, `width` field, but does not have `layout_below`...
Thanks for any help!

Comment: This will help: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277196/can-i-set-androidlayout-below-at-runtime-programmatically)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add view programmatically to RelativeLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418929/add-view-programmatically-to-relativelayout)

Answer (score 12):

with `addRule`

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, idOfTheViewBelow);
```

Comment: And i could apply it to the LinearLayout?

Comment: @ADK: You get the `LinearLayout`'s current `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`, then modify them. Or, if this is a newly-created `LinearLayout`, you create a new `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` as the answer shows. The class of the `LayoutParams` is determined by the *parent* (`RelativeLayout`), not the *child* (`LinearLayout`).

Comment: I try to do this:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) mContainerView.getLayoutParams();
                p.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.animView);
                mButtonContainer.setLayoutParams(p);
, where mContainerView - parent RelativeLayout, and mButtonContainer child LinearLayout....i`ve got an ClassCastException error =(