# make text view for every item in Arraylist

Tags: android

I'm making application that send a String Array list to another activity and in the another activity it takes all the items and make text view for every item but i don't know how to do it.

this is my first activity code:

```
package com.TOF.versus;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    Button exitBtn;
    EditText namesTxt;
    TextView namesNumber;
    Button namesBtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        exitBtn=(Button) findViewById(R.id.exitBtn);
        exitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        namesNumber=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.namesNumber);
        namesTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.namesTxt);
        namesBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.namesBtn);
        inputName();
    }
    public void inputName(){
        final ArrayList <String> names= new ArrayList<String>();
        namesTxt.setSingleLine();
        namesTxt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    names.add(namesTxt.getText().toString());
                    namesNumber.setText(Integer.toString(names.size()));
                    namesTxt.setText("");
                    namesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Intent send = new Intent(v.getContext(), Names.class);
                            send.putStringArrayListExtra("E",names);
                            startActivity(send);
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            }});}}
```

and this the second activity code that i don't know how to make the text view for :

```
package com.TOF.versus;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Names extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button backBtn;
    RelativeLayout names_layout;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.names_layout);
        backBtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
        backBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        names_layout=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.db2_root);
        TextView text=new TextView(this);
        Intent recv=getIntent();
        ArrayList<String> str= recv.getStringArrayListExtra("E");
        text.setText(str.get());
        text.setLayoutParams(new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        names_layout.addView(text);
        System.out.println(str);
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't u use listview in Names activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need to loop through the ArrayList you created with the list you got from 
the Intent.

```
ArrayList<String> str= recv.getStringArrayListExtra("E");

for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        TextView text = new TextView(this);
        text.setText(str.get(i));
        text.setLayoutParams(new          
ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        names_layout.addView(text);
}
```

so this loops through the str `ArrayList`, creates a new instance of a `TextView`, gets the string corresponding to that position in the array, sets the text, layout params and then add it's to your layout.

**Edit**:

I would reccomend using a `LinearLayout` with an orientation assigned to it rather than a `RelativeLayout` for `names_layout` if you are adding views dynamically, unless you learn how to apply rules.

Example taken from [How do I specify layout_below programmatically for a LinearLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985646/how-do-i-specify-layout-below-programmatically-for-a-linearlayout)

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
relativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, idOfTheViewBelow);
```

**Edit 2**:

> What is the difference between LinearLayout and RelativeLayout?

This should provide enough information for you to understand

1. [What are the differences between LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, and AbsoluteLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4905370/what-are-the-differences-between-linearlayout-relativelayout-and-absolutelayou)
2. [LinearLayout example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-linearlayout-example/)

Comment: what is the difference between linearLayout and RelativeLayout