# Create buttons in sequential order programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to parse text, and create for each word - button, but i don't know how to arrange them one after the other

```
String s = "Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting";
String[] q = s.split(" ");
for (int i = 0; i < q.length; i++) {
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    myButton.setText(q[i]);

    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);
    layout.addView(myButton, params);

}
```

[image: img]

Comment: I suggest you try a `TableLayout`. Dynamically building a RelativeLayout like that will be difficult

Comment: I second cricket_007's comment. It would be neigh impossible to fill a relativelayout like that using a for loop.

Comment: addrules but will cannot be with loop

Comment: In your case, I think you might want to consider using horizontal LinearLayouts inside another vertical layout. You can check when adding a view to the LinearLayout would cause that view to get cut off of the side of the display and then put it in another LinearLayout below that. - if you don't want to use tablelayout that is.

Comment: This is an example of a decent question that doesn't get enough upvotes.

Comment: The screenshot on the right looks shows that all your buttons are there. They are just stacked on top of each other.  Consider converting to use gridview and adapter or the flowlayout library answered below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this custom library: [FlowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout)

While you're adding views inside `FlowLayout`, it automatically wraps when there is no space for the next item.

Answer (score 2):

There's not much wrong about your approach, it's only that `relative layout` as name suggests requires child views to have some parameters to align the views relative to them e.g. above, below etc. As a result you are getting views overlapping each other and hence only the last added view is visible being on top.

Use `FlowLayout` instead and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `RelativeLayout` parameters as in example below

> Heres an example to get you started, fill in the rest as applicable:
>
> ```
> TextView tv = new TextView(mContext);
> RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
>     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
> params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
> params.leftMargin = 107
> ...
> mRelativeLayout.addView(tv, params);
> ```
>
> The docs for RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and the constructors are
>   [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#RelativeLayout.LayoutParams%28int,%20int%29)
>
> From: [How to add a view programmattically to RelativeLayout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418929/how-to-add-a-view-programmattically-to-relativelayout)

Check the link below to get more useful informations.

Hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, you should change the upper limits of the for, to a variable.

```
public class MainActivity
        extends Activity
        implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            TableLayout layout = new TableLayout (this);
            layout.setLayoutParams( new TableLayout.LayoutParams(4,5) );

            layout.setPadding(1,1,1,1);

            for (int f=0; f<=13; f++) {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                for (int c=0; c<=9; c++) {
                    Button b = new Button (this);
                    b.setText(""+f+c);
                    b.setTextSize(10.0f);
                    b.setTextColor(Color.rgb( 100, 200, 200));
                    b.setOnClickListener(this);
                    tr.addView(b, 30,30);
                } // for
                layout.addView(tr);
            } // for

            super.setContentView(layout);
        } // ()

        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((Button) view).setText("*");
            ((Button) view).setEnabled(false);
        }
    } // class
```