# OnItemSelectedListener of Spinner don't call when it's item selected

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

The following code is my Spinner init code , But when it's item selected, The callback listener don't call

```
 private void showSelectDialog(final List datas, final AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener onItemClickListener) {
        if (EmptyUtil.isCollectionNotEmpty(datas) || datas.size() > 1) {
            final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);

            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_item, datas);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinner.setDropDownHorizontalOffset(DeviceUtil.getDeviceWidth(this) / 2);
            spinner.setDropDownVerticalOffset(DeviceUtil.getDeviceHeight(this) / 2);
            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    ToastTool.showToast(PlaceanOrderActivity.this,"onItemSelected");
                    onItemClickListener.onItemSelected(adapterView,view,i,l);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                    onItemClickListener.onNothingSelected(adapterView);
                }
            });
            spinner.performClick();
        }
    }
```

Who has ideas for this problem, Thanks for first!

Comment: have you add spinner in any view? [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10418929/how-to-add-a-view-programmattically-to-relativelayout)

Comment: @ImtiyazKhalani no

Comment: you have to add you spinner to activity view/layout.

Comment: @ImtiyazKhalani   thanks, it works