# add text view during run time to relativlayout

Tags: android, xml, textview

In my android project, I get a `string` from my server and from that `string` put the value inside a `textview`.

**XML**:

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/scorelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">
```

**Java**:

```java
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.scorelayout);
TextView Score = new TextView(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);
relativeLayout.addView(Score, layoutParams);
```

Comment: Add a text to your textview.

Comment: It's unclear what problem you're having with your current solution

Comment: It doesn't work the textview doesn't appear for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution for you will be to set your `TextView` in xml and set

`android:visibility="gone"`

And when you have to show your text just do it like

```
myTextView.setText(myText);
myTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But if you are looking just an answer how to add view programmatically here is a link https://stackoverflow.com/a/10419021/5422725

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by these three steps:

**Step1:** You can make use a textview in Android and make it invisible(Xml property).

**Step2:** After making the textview you can assign the dynamic string which you are getting to the textview by the help of java in java class by **setText()** method.

**step3:** make its visibility to visible by using java code.

I hope that will help.
If you need more help regarding this feel free.